# How to test my "in app purchase" (really, not with sandbox users) in TestFlight?

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, testflight

Do you know, how I can test my subscription via TestFlight with a real ID? The whole process works with a sandbox account but I want to test with an actual purchase.

I explain me. I have a pool of beta testers in TestFlight and I want that my testers try to purchase in my app but the item is not validate from apple (the first version of this app is not published). Does the item need to be verified from Apple for users to purchase?

Thanks for your answers!

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

So I called Apple directly and the answer is NO ... As long as an item is not validated, any real transaction can be made.